# Problem with Xpath PHP

Tags: php, xpath

Im tring to access some links through Google using xpath. The below does works fine and all the links are shown.

```
    $query = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");

    for ($x=0 ; $x < $query -> length; $x++)
    {
        $href=$query->item($x);

               $url=$href->getAttribute('href');
        echo $url."<br>";
    }
```

But when i try the below xpath nothing is shown..Im sure that the xpath is correct coz its evaluated and the result is shown in xpather..

```
/html/body[@id='gsr']/div[@id='cnt']/div[@id='res']/div[1]/ol/li/div//cite
    for ($x=0 ; $x < $query -> length; $x++)
    {
        $href=$query->item($x);

               $url=$href->getAttribute('cite');
        echo $url."<br>";
    }
```

can some one please tell me what i am doin wrong? any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Can you provide an example url to test the script against? Or can we use just _any_ google page?

Comment: The expression is necessarily complex. You can reduce it to: `//div[@id='res']/div[1]/ol/li/div//cite` as IDs are unique.
And you are not accessing an `a` element at all with this expression so where should the links come from?

Comment: To debug, truncate your long XPath and try successively appending bit by bit to see at which point it starts to give no results - e.g. first `/html/body`, then `/html/body[@id='gsr']`, then `/html/body[@id='gsr']/div`, etc.

Comment: @VolkerK im trying the normal Google search page...  @Felix im trying to access the values within the cite tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath expression selects 'cite' elements, then you are calling getAttribute('cite') on those element nodes. I don't think HTML 'cite' elements are supposed to have an attribute of the same name. Maybe instead of calling getAttribute('cite') on the 'cite' element nodes you rather want to access $href->textContent.